# Running yolov5 with webcam inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, yolov5, xcb, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to do inference with a yolov5 model on the webcam stream from a Nvidia Jetson Nano within a Docker container.  On both, my Windows PC and Jetson, I get the error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" 
even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.

Aborted
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /yolov5_aiss

COPY requirements.txt . 

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN apt install -y libxkbcommon-x11-0

CMD ["python", "./app/detect.py", "--weights","./app/weights/best.pt", "--source", "0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

**Note**

Headless mode can't use `--view-img` flag of `detect.py`